# blender export fbx material color wrong

Tags: export, blender, fbx

When I export my *blender* scene as `.fbx` file and try to open it in *Autodesk's Fbx Review* afterwards, all material colors seems lost or changed:

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to maintain the colors?

Answer (score 0):

It is very common for FBX Reviewer, and I think that's because FBX Reviewer uses another strange shader which makes everything brighter. That's just FBX Reviewer's problem and the program has just a few options to change. When you import your FBX file to another program such as Unity or MAX, the color's gonna be okay.